# Dundas Gauge for ASP.NET by Microsoft

Tags: charts, dundas, gauge

A couple of questions following Dundas acquisition by Microsoft:

1. Is Microsoft planning to support/expose the Dundas ASP.NET gauge control?
2. Are all the features that previously existed in Dundas ASP.NET chart control available in the ASP.NET 4.0 chart control? How easy is it to upgrade an existing ASP.NET application to use this control instead of the Dundas control?

Thank you,
Gai.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about **Dundas Gauge for .NET** and download it for Visual Studio 2003, 2005 and 2008 [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3916AC54-CB19-4E68-A439-430DF526CAFC). Apparently, there is not yet a .Net 4.0 version.

In the [Samples Environment for .NET Framework 4 Chart Controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) in the comments, there is this from a Dundas expert in 2008:

> Gauges is another visualization our
>   team would like to add. We do not have
>   the exact time line when this is going
>   to happen.

Comment: Hi DOK,The first part is not relevant for me since it's the original Dundas offering. The second part helps, but I need more information. Thanks.